# How to build distance measuring device that can only detect red light from a common red laser

Tags: photodiode

I want to make a distance measuring device. Using common red laser. what receiver  should I use to detect the red laser light only? a more sensitive to red light.

Do an Arduino UNO capable of this?

Comment: Use a red light filter. You can try cheap read plastics with random filtering or get fancy ones with specific wavelengths.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Physical method**

A quick method would be to just use a filtering lens. You will need to buy a lens specifically made to pass light at the wavelength of the laser. 
Common wavelength for cheap laser diodes is typically 650nm.

[image: red lens]

Simply filtering by red light may still lead to a noisy signal though, depending on the environment.

**Software Method**

Another way to filter out other sources of light would be to have the laser send a specific signal. That way, the receiver can ignore everything else. Software based filtering must also be processed at fast enough speeds, which can be quite fast for short distances.

The signal could be encoded in a way to reduce false-positives. One example would be to simply send a defined number of quick pulses at defined intervals. All other received signals can be rejected.

The duration of the signal should be short enough so as not to collide with returning reflections.
It is important to consider [Maximum Unambiguous Range.](http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/Maximum%20Unambiguous%20Range.en.html) This plays a role in determining the usable values for a signal's frequency and duration.

[image: Maximum Unambiguous Range Graph]

The signal can only travel so far between transmission periods. The shorter the period, the shorter the possible 'certain' distance measurement. So both the desired update interval of the measurement, as well as the expected maximum distance, also play a role in what the encoded laser signal can be. Longer update periods can reduce error.

Combining the physical filter with a software filter can dramatically reduce false positives, even with other distance measuring lasers in the area.

Comment: do Arduino capable of this?